# Phonegap Splash Screen (ios)

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I can't seem to get my splash screen to show instead of the default. I have these lines in my config.xml:

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
<gap:splash src="splash/screen1.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
```

I have splash.png in both the upper root and the root of www (not sure which is the right one). I'm using the regular iPhone simulator (not 4 or 5) and I've also tried building/hydrating and sending to my 3gs and it still uses the default. I also tried replacing the default splash screen files in the Resources/splash/ folder but that doesn't work either.

Edit: Also tried putting in every type of width/height specified for iphones, still no go.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot Phonegap can be a buggy POS sometimes. I had to delete the app from my device then re-add it (not hydrating) and the splash screen shows now. Still not working on the simulator, though.